# Out of Memory Error - On Sorting Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code.  Which was working fine but now I'm getting an error.  "Run-time error'7': Out of Memory"  Below is my code:

```
Sub SpiltData()

Dim tmpArr As Variant, rCell As Range, v, i As Long, v2(), J As Long, K As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, n As Long

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Hours Sorted")  'You need to specify a sheet here

v = ws1.Range("J6").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim v2(1 To UBound(v, 1) * 100, 1 To UBound(v, 2))
n = 1

For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
tmpArr = Split(v(i, 10), Chr(10))
For K = 0 To UBound(tmpArr)
    For J = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
        v2(n, J) = v(i, J)
    Next J
    v2(n, 10) = tmpArr(K)
    n = n + 1
Next K
Next i

ws2.Range("A1").Resize(n, UBound(v2, 2)) = v2

End Sub
```

Is there something I can do differently?

Comment: are you sure `UBound(v, 1) * 100` is needed this large? some things you could do differently is use `Redim Preserve v2()` , wich has the problem of being able to only redim the 2nd dimension, but you could reverse the dimensions inside v2, and lastly use `transpose`when writing to `ws2`

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with a huge selection, and your carriage return delimited data in position 10 of your array is large then you are resulting in "Huge x Large" number of results, all held in memory until it's dumped back out into `ws2`.

Alternatively, you can iterate through your range and write out as you encounter values. Keeping your variables nice and small and, presumably, your code easier to understand and debug. To make this work quicker, you can shut off the `application.screenupdating` toggle.

```
Sub SpiltData()
    Dim rngRead As Range
    Dim rngReadRow As Range
    Dim rngReadCell As Range
    Dim arrSplit As Variant
    Dim intWriteRow As Integer

    'initialize intWriteRow
    intWriteRow = 1

    'get that range
    Set rngReadRow = Sheets("Data").Range("J6").CurrentRegion

    'loop through each row
    For Each rngReadRow In rngReadRow.Rows

        'split your carriage return delimited cell into an array
        arrSplit = Split(rngReadRow.Cells(1, 11), Chr(10))

        'iterate the array and write out
        For Each arrItem In arrSplit

            'by iterating each cell in the readrow
            For Each rngReadCell In rngReadRow.Cells

                'and writing it to the other worksheet
                Sheets("Hours Sorted").Cells(intWriteRow, rngReadCell.Column).Value = rngReadCell                   

                'increment the row to which we are writing
                intWriteRow = intWriteRow + 1

            Next rngReadCell

        'and now write the split out value in the array
        Sheets("Hours Sorted").Cells(intWriteRow, 11) = arrItem

        Next arrItem
    Next rngReadRow

End Sub
```

This will probably have to be tweaked a small bit since I converted from arrays to ranges and made some assumptions, but it will get you in the ballpark and excel will crank on this all day long if it needs to and your main limit is the number of rows in excel instead of your ram.